# Access VBA : how to copy the current index into a other table

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm trying to write This Programm:

```
     Function funktion()
        Dim db As DAO.Database
        Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
        Dim rt As DAO.Recordset
        Set db = CurrentDb

        Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("All")

Do While Not rs.EOF


Set rk = db.OpenRecordset("Archive")

'here I want to copy(append) the current index(of Table"All") into the next free
 index (of table "archive") 


Do something


    rs.MoveNext
Loop
```

my programm works well just I need to append the current row from "All" into the next free row from table "Archive".

Thank you for your help

Comment: yes, it ist doesen't work in vba like that: SELECT * INSERT INTO [Archive] SELECT * FROM [All];

Comment: yes , but it doesn't work like that : INSERT INTO [Archive] SELECT * FROM [All];

Comment: yes , that's exactly what I looking for, but  I want just the current row in the loop block.

Comment: CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO [Archive] SELECT * FROM [All];"  append all the table evry time, when the loop ends , there are aggregates

Comment: step1 open [All]     LOOP{the loop begins at row1 . step2(copy this row and append ist to [Archive] step3(loop next row) } . its now understandable ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here´s a example of how you can do this using ADO and not DAO to access data.... in example above.. i add all records to another table... but easily you can just add the current record in your loop...

```
Dim cnn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim rs2 As ADODB.Recordset

Set cnn = CurrentProject.Connection
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
Set rs2 = New ADODB.Recordset

'open main recordset (TDetPed)
rs.Open "SELECT TDetPed.* FROM TDetPed WHERE CodPed = " & CodPed & "", cnn, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic


'open clone table recordset (TDetPedTemp)
rs2.Open "TDetPedTemp", cnn, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic

'move to first record of main table
rs.MoveFirst

'add record by record in clone table(rs2) from maintable(rs)
Do Until rs.EOF
rs2.AddNew
rs2("CodPed") = rs("CodPed")
rs2("CodDetPed") = rs("CodDetPed")
rs2("CodInterno") = rs("CodInterno")
rs2("DescrDetPed") = rs("DescrDetPed")
rs2("DescontoDetPed") = rs("DescontoDetPed")
rs2("CodProd") = rs("CodProd")
rs2("PreçoDetPed") = rs("PreçoDetPed")
rs2("QtdeDetPed") = rs("QtdeDetPed")

'update current added record in clone table
rs2.Update

'move to next record in main table
rs.MoveNext
'Move para o proximo registro do detalhe do pedido
Loop

'close everthing
rs.Close
rs2.Close
cnn.Close
'clean everthing
Set rs = Nothing
Set rs2 = Nothing
Set cnn = Nothing
```

Comment: exactly, this the solution what I looked for. Thank very much

Answer (score 0):

Just completing the answer... a simple example using DAO (Data Access Objetcs) and not ADO(Active Data Objetcs). (more info https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa261340%28v=vs.60%29.aspx / http://www.utteraccess.com/wiki/index.php/Choosing_between_DAO_and_ADO)

```
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set rs = dbsNorthwind.OpenRecordset("Tbl1")    
    rs.AddNew
    rs!Cidade = "Curitiba"
    rs!Country = "Brazil"       
    '.... others fields    
    rs.Update
```